# Keyboard and mouse events # Accessbility

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mouseevent, keyboard-events

How to write conditions for an automatic mouse click in the UI when we press any key on the keyboard.

I'm Working on the Accessibility Part ->
My Scenario is we are having banner which is displayed when the page loads initially. for that until we close that banner the focus should be inside that banner.

I have tried the onKeyDown event. when we trigger the onKeyDown event by using e.preventDefault() the focus is hidden. I need to get that focus again when I click any key on the keyboard.

Thanks in Advance.

```
    handleTab = (e) => {
    let tabKey = false
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
      e.preventDefault()
       tabKey = true
      }
if(tabKey) {
 # here I need an automatic browser click event. so that when I hit the tab key it will go inside of that banner
    }
onKeyDown = {this.handleTab()}
```

Comment: Please post existing `onKeyDown`

Comment: onKeyDown = {this.handleTag}

handleTag = (e) => {
if (e.keyCode === 9) {
  e.preventDefault()
}
}

Comment: You should attach it to the question @RevanthPydisetti

Comment: I guess it's `handleTab` not `handleTag`. Also what should be clicked ? Is the click receiver inside or outside the component ? Please post more code too.

Comment: handleTab = (e) => {
        let tabKey = false
        if (e.keyCode === 9) {
          e.preventDefault()
           tabKey = true
          }
    if(tabKey) {
     # here i need automatic browser click event. so that when i hit tab key it will go inside of that banner
        }
    onKeyDown = {this.handleTab()}

Comment: Is the banner inside or outside your component ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) property to prevent tab navigation outside the banner.

```html
    <input type="text" tabIndex="-1"/>
```

I created small demo to test: https://codepen.io/mich_life/pen/vYRMpqe

Comment: Thanks. Let me check and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) documentation has to say about `keyCode`:

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

[key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) which is a textual representation of the pressed key should be used instead & has been [supported since Internet Explorer 9](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-key).

Since you haven't specified, if the banner is inside or outside your component, I am going by outside.

```
handleTab=(evt)=> {
    if(evt.key == 'Tab') {
        evt.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('banner').focus();
    }
}
```

If it's rendered inside your component, use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks.. Let me check and get back to you